# asp.net webpages(razor) webmail helper send body as html

Tags: email, razor, webmatrix, webmail

I am able to send E-mail via the Webmail helper. However, I want to send the message with a body which contains HTML table. Can someone clarify if this is possible in Webmatrix webmail helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just specify `isBodyHtml: true` in the `Send` method:

```
var customerRequest = "<p>Help!"</p>";
WebMail.Send(to: email,
            subject: "Help request from - " + customerName,
            body: customerRequest,
            isBodyHtml: true
);
```

See here for more guidance: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/email-and-search/11-adding-email-to-your-web-site